# Default order behavior in oracle database if column values are the same

Tags: oracle, plsql, sql-order-by

Imagine a table (`my_table`):

```
id  modified_date
--  -------------------
5   2022-05-12 07:00:00
1   2022-05-12 07:00:00
2   2022-05-12 07:00:00
22  2022-05-12 07:00:00
4   2022-05-12 07:00:00
3   2022-05-12 07:00:00
```

My select statement is as follow:

```sql
SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY modified_date ASC, id ASC;
```

Which gives me:

```
id  modified_date
--  -------------------
1   2022-05-12 07:00:00
2   2022-05-12 07:00:00
3   2022-05-12 07:00:00
4   2022-05-12 07:00:00
5   2022-05-12 07:00:00
22  2022-05-12 07:00:00
```

By default, how does Oracle order things if `id ASC` was omitted when the sort column values are the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't specify `order by`, then the outcome is *unknown*. As Oracle stores data into table in *unordered* way (think of it as of a basket full of apples - which apple was first added? Which was the 5th? The last? You don't know), selecting rows might end up with a different sort every time you run the `select` statement.

You - most probably - won't notice that, especially on small tables which aren't modified. But, for large tables that are frequently modified (rows being deleted, new rows added, ...), "today's" `select` might (and probably will) return result which is different from "yesterday's" `select`.

Basically, you don't know what you'll get.

Back to apples? If you say "give me apples and sort them by their weight", then yes - you'll first get the smallest apple, while the last one will be the largest. That's what `order by` does.